# Running setup/teardown tasks during stb test task

Tags: scala, unit-testing, sbt

I try to configure sbt to run a setup task at the beginning and a tear down task at the end of myProject/test command.

My build.sbt is here:

```
name := "ch-2"

version := "1.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.specs2" % "specs2_2.10" % "1.14" % "test"

lazy val common = (
  Project("common", file("common")).
    settings()
  )

lazy val subPro = (
  Project("sub", file("subA")).settings(
  ).dependsOn(common)
    settings(libraryDependencies += "org.specs2" % "specs2_2.10" % "1.14" % "test" )
  )

val startS = taskKey[Unit]("Start")
val stopS = taskKey[Unit]("Stop")
startS := { println("Running start")}
stopS := { println("Running stop")}

testOptions in Test in subPro += Tests.Setup { () => startS.value }
testOptions in Test in subPro += Tests.Cleanup { () => stopS.value }
```

The actual dummy test class is here:

```
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
/**
  * Created by jk on 26.3.2017.
  */
object FooSpec extends Specification {
  "The TEST method" should {
    "blaa blaa 1" in {
      println("test 1 running...")
      true
    }
    "blaa blaa 2" in {
      println("test 2 running...")
      true
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the tests for project sub, I get following output:

```
> sub/test
Running stop
Running start
[info] Updating {file:/home/jk/workspace/sbt-in-action/ch2/}sub...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/jk/workspace/sbt-in-action/ch2/subA/target/scala-2.10/test-classes...
test 1 running...
test 2 running...
[info] FooSpec
[info] 
[info] The TEST method should
[info] + blaa blaa 1
[info] + blaa blaa 2
[info]  
[info]  
[info] Total for specification FooSpec
[info] Finished in 18 ms
[info] 2 examples, 0 failure, 0 error
[info] 
[info] Passed: Total 2, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 2
[success] Total time: 3 s, completed Mar 26, 2017 7:09:34 PM
```

Why is stop task run even before compilation is finished and how to fix it so that it is run after all test cases are run (despite the result of the test cases)?

Also the start task should run after successfull compilation but before first test case. How to fix these?

Comment: Any reason why FooSpec is an object rather than a class?

Comment: I just copied it from an example (where it was object for some reason) to get the sample code running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about doing it like this instead?

```
def startS(): Unit = { println("Running start")}
def stopS(): Unit = { println("Running stop")}

testOptions in Test in subPro += Tests.Setup { () => startS() }
testOptions in Test in subPro += Tests.Cleanup { () => stopS() }
```

Comment: Also, I think the discussion here explains why it doesn't quite work the way you would expect when you use tasks: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Custom-Settings.html#Execution+semantics+of+tasks

Comment: Thanks for the link. It explains at least partially this problem ("invoking value method on tasks will not be evaluated strictly").